# Rounding Up to Next Odd Number

Tags: functions, integers

I want a function $f(x)$ that rounds any $x$ to the next odd integer. For example $f(5.5)=7,f(4)=5,f(7)=7$. It does not have to be continuous nor differentiable. When I say "function", I mean an explicit definition so I can graph it on graphing software (like Desmos). For example, something like $\mathbb{ceil}(\frac{x}{2})-1$ would be accepted, if it were right.

Comment: You have such a function.  Your first sentence defines it nicely.  It definitely is not continuous or differentiable at odd integers, but is continuous and differentiable at all other points.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, I should have been more clear. I want a explicit definition so I can graph it on graphing software, like Desmos.

Comment: Does Desmos have a "ceiling" function? In that case $f(x)=2\lceil \frac{x-1}2\rceil+1$. If thee is no ceiling, perhaps ther eis a floor function? Then $f(x)=1-2\lfloor \frac{1-x}2\rfloor$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes it has both. I'm waiting for 6 minutes to pass so I can accept.

Comment: A pet peeve of mine is that a function is not a magical incantation.  If you want a function that rounds up to the nears odd integer then say: "$f(x) =n$ where $n$ is the next odd integer".  That *is* valid mathematics. ... but okay.  $f(x)=2\lceil \frac x 2\rceil -1 $ should do it.  " It does not have to be continuous"  Well, there is only one function that does what you want and it *isn't* continuous or differential so it *can't* be.

Comment: I guess what bugs me is that the "ceiling" or "floor" function is just as artificial as any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define $f(x)=\lceil \frac{x+1}{2} \rceil \cdot 2 - 1$

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that looks "mathematical" you can say
$$f(x)=2\left\lceil \frac {x-1}2 \right\rceil +1$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.